# Get LWC in Password Pages Menu

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page, page-override

I'm trying to figure out how to get a Lightning Web Component (LWC), NOT AURA, into the Experience Page Builder menu on the `Password Pages` menu in the `Administration > Login & Registration > Password Pages`. I've looked into the MetaData on the components that are already in there, but there is nothing that seems to indicate it should be selectable in that menu.

Here are screen shots

[image]

[image]